# Trouble Dropping Temporary Table Seen in Binlog

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql, temp-tables, mysqlbinlog

This question is regarding a MySQL 5.7 database, running on CloudSQL.  The binlog files for this database were growing unusually large over the last week.  Upon analysis of those files, I noticed the statement "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE need_to_get" repeated millions of times, about 100 times per second, over the last 5 days.  Here is an example:

```
#210207  3:21:51 server id xxxx end_log_pos 165359 CRC32 0xfe1f73b8      Query   thread_id=7626438       exec_time=0     error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1612686111/*!*/;
SET @@session.pseudo_thread_id=7626438/*!*/;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `need_to_get` /* generated by server */
/*!*/;
```

After the server restarted, this behavior stopped.  It seems the server might have had trouble dropping the temporary table.  What could have caused this to happen?

Comment: I would guess CloudSQL has implemented this as a way to test that replication is working. I've never heard of MySQL doing it on its own.

Comment: It is expected that all the tables be removed when the instance is restarted as [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html) says. However, it sounds a bit strange the fact the statement "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE need_to_get" repeated millions of times. Did you notice an error message? That could help to know what happened.

Comment: @SamuelRomero I didn't notice any error message.